# Between & In operators- How can i give multiple conditions for a column in SQL

Tags: sql

If i want to find # of suppliers who supplied products in 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, all four years. how do i frame a query for that? 
Between and In operators does not work.

Comment: Datetime is an area where too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: What did you try so far, where do you get into troubles?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing information about your table, if the year is stored in a column then you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (year = '2010') OR (year = '2011') OR (year = '2012') OR (year = '2013');
```

if it's a type of DATETIME you can probably do

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DATETIMEcolumn BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

being 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' the default DATETIME format of MySQL, we don't know what you are using but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Date into Char and you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(SUPPLIERS) FROM 
(SELECT SUPPLIERS,Count(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(DATETIME_FIELD,'YYYY')) FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATETIME_FIELD,'YYYY') 
    IN 
('2010','2011','2012','2013')
GROUP BY SUPPLIERS 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(DATETIME_FIELD,'YYYY'))=4);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

```
select * from TableName 
where functionToExtractYear(DateColumn) in(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)

select * from TableName 
where functionToExtractYear(DateColumn) between 2010 and 2013

select * from TableName 
where DateColumn >= '2010-01-01' and DateColumn <= '2014-01-01'
```

The last is preferable at least in `Sql Server` because it will use possible index on `DateColumn`.

You have not specified the engine you use so `functionToExtractYear()` may vary between different products. For `Sql Server` it is `YEAR()`.